# How to SSH a server getting dynamic IPs from DHCP

Tags: networking, ssh, 17.10, dhcp

I have a `ubuntu` server at remote site to whom I access via SSH user@ip-address. 
IP is assigned from a DHCP server of remote site (for which I don't have access). After few reboots, the server's IP gets released and it gets new IP address. I then have to call someone at remote site to go and check the server's new IP so I can SSH.

Is there a way that I can SSH the machine via `hostname` (or any other configuration) without completely relying on the IP?

Comment: Best would be to talk to the DHCP admin and either assign a static entry for your MAC address in the DHCP server or make use of DDNS ( [dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) )

Comment: Why not set a static IP on the server?

Comment: @chili555 because I do not have any rights on remote site, and I am only allowed to connect to their preconfigured dhcp wire.

Comment: Can you make the remote machine somehow _publish_ its IP after booting? E.g. by sending you an email or writing it to some node with a known IP?